# Using Tableau Server Client (TSC) to Query data from a Tableau server datasource in Python bring that fetched datasource table in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, tableau-api, tsc

I am able to access datasources from my tableau server to python using TSC library, now I want to access the table using pandas dataframe, so that I can do some data wrangling in the data and store it offline.

I want to convert the datasource file in pandas format, where I will have all my columns/field and their respective values. the below code is working fine till

```
ds = server.datasources.get_by_id(datasource_id)
```

but when I am trying to populate this in csv python throws an attribute error.

here is my code:

```
datasource_id = "05cfc3-iuwe-fli78-72cs jyg-ad" # "Rules" data source ID 

tableau_auth = TSC.PersonalAccessTokenAuth(my_auth)
server = TSC.Server(my_server)
server.version = '3.1'
with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):
    ds = server.datasources.get_by_id(datasource_id)
    server.datasources.populate_csv(ds)  # code not working from here
    with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as file:
        for chunk in ds.csv:
            file.write(chunk)
        file.seek(0)
        df = pd.read_csv(file,encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
        
df.head()
```

can anyone please help me to get the solution please.
Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks

I have successfully connected to Tableau Server using the TSC library in Python and accessed the desired datasources. Now I need assistance in converting the datasource into a pandas dataframe for data manipulation and offline storage. However, I encounter an attribute error when attempting to populate the data into a CSV file. Any help to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The line where you are receiving your error is not an attribute of the datasource class. `populate_csv` will only work on the views class `views.populate_csv` If you want to download a datasource use the `datasources.download(YOUR DS ID)` function.

```
datasource_id = "05cfc3-iuwe-fli78-72cs jyg-ad" # "Rules" data source ID 

tableau_auth = TSC.PersonalAccessTokenAuth(my_auth)
server = TSC.Server(my_server)
server.version = '3.1'
with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):
    file_path = server.datasources.download(datasource_id)
    print("\nDownloaded the file to {0}.".format(file_path))
```

This will print the filepath to your downloaded data source. If it is in a `.hyper` format you can then use the `tableauhyperapi` to convert it to a csv.

This example will walk you through reading from a `.hyper` after you download.

https://github.com/tableau/hyper-api-samples/blob/main/Community-Supported/hyper-to-csv/hyper-to-csv.py

Comment: My datasource has only one table, can you please show me here how can I convert the above hyper file to CSV?

Comment: I updated the code. I had another id in the line here: `with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):
            file_path = server.datasources.download(datasource_id)` and I have replaced it with your datasource_id variable. Let me know if that was the issue.

Comment: Hi @vizyourdata
I am able to download the datasouorce, but I want to use it in python in pandas dataframe. can you help me to write a code where I can put the above data source in pandas dataframe and do some data wrangling and then export it to csv file?

Comment: Hi @vizyourdata , The file is in .tsdx format not in hyper format. how to convert that into CV?